# What is the largest prime less than 2^31?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, online-resources

I'm sorry for this kind of specific question, I'd love if you could link to resources (prime lists, etc) that can answer similar questions more generically.

Comment: Mathematica should be able to answer this question quickly; it has a function that will tell you how many primes there are less than 2^{31} and another that tells you what the nth prime is.  Use one, then the other.

Comment: These are all great answers.  Thank you everyone.

Comment: @Qiaochu: A shortcut is `NextPrime[2^31,-1]`.

Comment: ...and it works on Wolfram Alpha too: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NextPrime%5B2%5E31%2C-1%5D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.prime-numbers.org/prime-number-2147480000-2147485000.htm tells you that it's 2147483647 (about 2/3rds of the way down, third column).  This website seems like a good resource if you're looking for lots of primes.

Comment: Thank you, that list was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 19):

It is $2^{31}-1$. You might want to check Mersenne prime for similar details.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime

Comment: Interestingly this is one of the four known Mersenne double prime.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Mersenne_number

Comment: The fact that this is a prime is taken advantage by pseudo random number generators on $32$ bit machines.

Comment: The first proof of primality was given by Euler, and it remained the largest-known prime for nearly 100 years.

Comment: Do you have a link to the proof @douglas?

Comment: Here's Euler's proof: http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~euler/pages/E461.html  Although you might be more interested in the wikipedia page:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647